# Fullcalendar: keep track of event changes in database

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using the calendar now, and it works well.

I want to add a database record every time an event is moved/resized/etc. to keep a history log.

Once an event is moved for instance, I will use ajax to add the information to my db, but I don't know how to capture the original time and new time.

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
     events: [
    // events here
],
editable: true,
eventDrop: function(event, delta, revertFunc) {

    alert(event.title + " was dropped on " + event.start.format());

    if (!confirm("Are you sure about this change?")) {
        revertFunc();
    }

}
```

Does the delta value hold this information so I can use it for my records?

Comment: From the docs: "delta is a Duration Object that represents the amount of time the event was moved by." If that's not clear, please let me know what part of it you don't understand. It seems trivially obvious that you can derive the old start time using a combination of the new time and the duration of time by which it was shifted.

Comment: ... Well then ...